# Azure Mobile Apps’ Easy Tables boundaries and limits

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I would like to know the limits of easy tables, for example, size of the rows and row count limits, and other important consideration

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Easy Tables is also known as "No-Code Table or API" which enables you to write zero code to create a backend for your mobile app using Azure App Service Mobile Apps. The Easy Tables are mobile friendly, ODATA friendly and are backed by Azure SQL Database. See [Setting up Easy Tables in Azure App Service Mobile Apps](http://www.kashyapas.com/2015/12/26/setting-up-easy-tables-in-azure-app-service-mobile-apps/).

So, the limits of Easy Tables depend on what price tier of Azure SQL Database you choose. You can check out the [SQL Database pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/) page for more details.